# Last week of the year is given attributed to the next year

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

The last week of 2021 is assigned as 2022 in `pandas.date_range()` function, whereas, in exception of Saturday and Sunday (1st and 2nd of January), the rest of the days fall under 2021.

```py
import pandas as pd

for x in pd.date_range(start='2021-12-01', end='2022-01-04', freq='W'):
    print('date: ', x, '\tweek: ', x.week, '\tyear: ', x.year)
```

```py
Output:

date:  2021-12-05 00:00:00      week:  48       year:  2021
date:  2021-12-12 00:00:00      week:  49       year:  2021
date:  2021-12-19 00:00:00      week:  50       year:  2021
date:  2021-12-26 00:00:00      week:  51       year:  2021
date:  2022-01-02 00:00:00      week:  52       year:  2022
```

The output makes sense, however, this doesn't work under the filtration that I am using:

```py
df[(df['date'].year == x.year) & (df['date'].week == x.week)]
```

Currently this issue is fixed with a band-aid, but hoping to have it fully functioning for a next year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a feature, not a bug.
Week numbering is based on ISO 8601, specifically: "If 1 January is on a Friday, Saturday or Sunday, it is in week 52 or 53 of the previous year". You need to change your application logic to include that edge case.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates

Also, according to pandas documentation:

"`weekofyear` and `week` have been deprecated. Please use `DatetimeIndex.isocalendar().week` instead."

If you switch to both `x.isocalendar().week` and `x.isocalendar().year` you will get consistent, although not intuitive outputs:

```
date:  2021-12-19 00:00:00      week:  50       year:  2021
date:  2021-12-26 00:00:00      week:  51       year:  2021
date:  2022-01-02 00:00:00      week:  52       year:  2021
date:  2022-01-09 00:00:00      week:  1        year:  2022
```

Comment: Thanks, how could I see `.isocalendar()` for datetime series? (df['datetime'] column)

Comment: @AkmalSoliev Not sure I understood your question;
your x (`for x in pd.date_range`) already have that property. You just have to replace x.week with x.isocalendar().week, likewise for .year

Comment: the date_range object I will use to match with the column, the issue I am having is that 1st of January will still appear as 2022 when called `.year`, hence wondering if I can extract `isocalendar()` from datetime column? or will need to convert it to Timestamp?

Comment: df['date'].isocalendar().year does not work?

Comment: Nope, getting, `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'isocalendar'`

Answer (score 0):

What you could do - you could apply your filtration on the *beginning of the week* day, using this property:

```
pd.Timestamp(2022, 1, 2).to_period('W').start_time
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Timestamp('2021-12-27 00:00:00')
```

So:

```
import pandas as pd

d = pd.DataFrame({"date":[pd.Timestamp(2022,1,2)]})

d[d["date"].dt.to_period('W').apply(lambda x: x.start_time.isocalendar()[:2] == (2021, 52))]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
        date
0 2022-01-02
```